# Spring Rest Template : 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring

I tried to get refresh token from some API.When pass values to service it's show 400 Bad Request.This I followed many links for solve this.I could fined same problem with correct answers.When I change my cord according to those answer but problem not solved.
I try to changes my cord following these answers.

[Answers 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276190/resttemplate-postforobject-error-org-springframework-web-client-httpclienterr), [Answers 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081397/org-springframework-web-client-httpclienterrorexception-400-null), [Answers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826887/spring-resttemplate-http-post-with-parameters-cause-400-bad-request-error), [Answers 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019212/org-springframework-web-client-httpclienterrorexception-400-bad-request) etc.

This is my method

```
public String genarateRefreshToken(String username , String password ,String authCode){

    String responseObj = null ;

    try{

        HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        final String url = "https://ideabiz.lk/apicall/token";
        RestTemplate rstTemp = new RestTemplate();
        rstTemp.getMessageConverters().add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        rstTemp.getMessageConverters().add(stringHttpMessageConverternew);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        multiMap.set("grant_type", "password");
        multiMap.set("username", username);
        multiMap.set("password",password);
        multiMap.set("scope", "PRODUCTION");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+authCode);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(multiMap, headers);
        responseObj = rstTemp.postForObject(url,entity, TokenResponse.class );

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseObj;


}
```

This is StackTrace

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:616)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:572)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:532)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:332)
at com.hameedia.test.service.HameediaTestService.genarateRefreshToken(HameediaTestService.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Mar 26, 2017 11:57:38 PM    org.apache.cxf.services.HameediaTestServiceService.HameediaTestServicePort.HameediaTestService
INFO: Outbound Message
```

If you have ideas please help me.

Comment: Did you log the request and check if the request is matching with working request . ??

Comment: Thanks balaji.Your correct.It was with my request.

Comment: I updated my post. "password " changed as "password" (remove space quotation marks of password)in this multiMap.set("grant_type", "password "); line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer according to  Balaji V answer.
I changed my request,

> multiMap.set("grant_type", "password ");

I removed space of "password " as "password". Also  changed multiMap.set("scope ", "PRODUCTION"); line. "scope " as "scope".

But again came another error.I had to change "TokenResponse " method data type as String. And return String.

Comment: You should remove your answer and update the question